# Dataflow advanced export filter by category

Tags: export, dataflow

I want to filter the exported products by category, but what I have isn't working:

```
<action type="catalog/convert_adapter_product" method="load">
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
    <var name="filter/type"><![CDATA[simple]]></var>
    <var name="filter/category"><![CDATA[my-category]]></var>
</action>

<action type="catalog/convert_parser_product" method="unparse">
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
    <var name="url_field"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_mapper_column" method="map">
    <var name="map">
        <map name="sku"><![CDATA[MPN/UPC]]></map>
        <map name="brand"><![CDATA[Manufacturer]]></map>
        <map name="name"><![CDATA[Product Name]]></map>
        <map name="product_link"><![CDATA[product_link]]></map>
        <map name="condition"><![CDATA[Product Condition]]></map>
        <map name="price"><![CDATA[Selling Price]]></map>
        <map name="shipping_costs"><![CDATA[Shipping costs]]></map>
        <map name="weight_box1"><![CDATA[Weight]]></map>
    </var>
    <var name="_only_specified">true</var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="unparse">
    <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
    <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
    <var name="fieldnames">true</var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="save">
    <var name="type">file</var>
    <var name="path">var/export</var>
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[catonly.csv]]></var>
</action>
```

Looks like `<var name="filter/category"><![CDATA[my-category]]></var>` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [Magento KB article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/introduction-to-magento-dataflow), it seems that we are limited to a set of predefined filters (name, sku, type, attribute_set, price/from, price/to, qty/from, qty/to, visibility, status)

To use another filter, you must create a small extension, example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7342066/729440

For categories, you'll want to load your category using `Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($your_cat_id_here);` and then use `addCategoryFilter`

Answer (score 1):

Although an accepted answer, I would like to place another alternative: Using profile definition to own adapter.

First step is to create your own advanced import/export profile.
You can simply copy the profile xml from the existing export profile located in system->import/export->dataflow profiles.

Once copied, adjust the adapter to your own adapter class

Example xml, with adapter changed:

```
<action type="viyet_importexport/convert_adapter_product" method="load">
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
</action>
<action type="catalog/convert_parser_product" method="unparse">
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
    <var name="url_field"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
</action>
<action type="dataflow/convert_mapper_column" method="map">
</action>
<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="unparse">
    <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
    <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
    <var name="fieldnames">true</var>
</action>
<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="save">
    <var name="type">file</var>
    <var name="path">var/export</var>
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[export_all_products.csv]]></var>
</action>
```

The important part is the first bit:

```
<action type="viyet_importexport/convert_adapter_product" method="load">
        <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
    </action>
```

Then define your own adapter class, extending the core adapter that is usually used.

```
class Viyet_ImportExport_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product
    extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product
{
    /**
     * Retrieve not loaded collection
     *
     * @param string $entityType
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection
     */
    protected function _getCollectionForLoad($entityType)
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($entityType.'_collection')
            ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
            ->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreId());
        $categoryObject = mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(Mage::getStoreConfig('importexport/attributes/category_id'));
        if($categoryObject->getId()) {
            $collection->addCategoryFilter($categoryObject);
        }
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

This then give you the ability to override the base class method that builds the collection, which you can then use to add a category filter.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the "Enhanced Product Grid" extension, see below:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-product-grid.html

Free to use this one.

Then, you have the ability to add a category filter to your manage products page in your admin area.

You can then extract just the category you want.

I think this is what you are looking for?

P.S. I would thoroughly recommend using Magmi for any imports of products:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_Wiki

Hope this helps?

Comment: While it could work, I really would like to know why the filter doesn't work on the advanced dataflow.

Comment: Yeah, understand what you mean. I haven't used the advanced dataflow in a while though so not sure I can help you any further there. We fell out with it some time ago due to limitations and slow uploads, and have used Magmi ever since.